# User keeps on suggesting offensive edit, can this be stopped?

Tags: discussion

For the third time in less than 2 days there is an attempt to get an highly offensive edit through for this question:

[On re-instating a suspended scientist](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/202853/on-re-instating-a-suspended-scientist)

Me and any other reviewer so far rejected the edit as spam, but what I can only assume is the same - anonymous - user is not giving up and keeps on suggesting that edit. They really stick to their agenda.

In the end this is only a minor incnvenience but it still wastes peoples' time. So my question, is there the possibility to block that user even though anonymous, or to block that question from being edited altogether? As it is not really possible to flag a suggested edit I am asking this question here.

Comment: There is supposed to be an [IP blocking system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118213/552049), but I suppose any such block is easily evaded.

Comment: or maybe the number of rejected edits is not yet high enough for the block

Comment: Possibly. I do not know what the cutoff is. That said, I think you're rather understating the extent and persistence of this vandalism "campaign" in the post. I count 10 such attempts over the last week in the review history.

Comment: @Anyon ok, than I was lucky not to have been the reviewer of all of these, but then probably the block should have kicked in by now.

Comment: The blocking system has a couple of known flaws. Would blocking all anonymous edits work for your site? Because that can be requested.

Comment: @Mast I personally think that would be a good idea, but I would put that up for voting and also see what the mods think.

Comment: I suspect [this rejected suggested edit](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/121904) is from the same anonymous user.

Comment: @Nobody probably yes, I thought the same thing - it came up shortly after I posted this question here, so it seemed a bit "revengy".

Comment: I saw another one of these edits today.  The vandal is nothing if not tenacious.

Comment: @Buzz, yeah, 6 times yesterday and they even started to do this with another question...

Comment: @Buzz I think the mere fact that pretty much only regulars of the Suggested edits review queue see it, is the best course of action. That's what we are here for.

Comment: Criminy, this jerk is persistent.

Comment: @Buzz Remember, always be civil :))))

Answer (score 7):

We moderators are aware of the situation and think that no intervention is necessary as of now. The system is working and, while it may be a bit annoying, we are not overwhelmed. If you see such an edit in the queue, just reject it as abusive.

While locking this particular question or disabling anonymous edits altogether is possible, we would consider it to do more harm than good in this case.

For whatever it’s worth, roughly two thirds of anonymous edits on this site were accepted (through review or the post’s author).

Comment: Do we know the anonymous user's IP address ? If we do, can we match it with the registered users' IP ? I have the guts feeling this anonymous user is a registered user.

Comment: and the edit suggestions keep on coming, I had two more since I posted this question.

Comment: aand another one

Comment: @Sursula: Remember: It takes more time for you to write this comment and me reading it than rejecting the edit.

Comment: I remember we force the users to register before they post to decrease spam posts. Can we do the same for Suggest Edit ?

Comment: @Nobody: That would go even further than disabling anonymous edits altogether.

Comment: New/Low rep (<2k) registered users can still do Suggested Edit. We already disable un-registered post which is almost anonymous post (they can always use fake user names). It's not that we don't want to reject bad edits. We do. But, too many bad edits are annoying and troublesome. Just like too many spams are annoying and troublesome.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I get what you mean, but: to me this feels bad on a more profound level. Its a bit like having someone write a low-key insult or a profanity with an erasable marker on my window each morning. It takes a second to wipe it away and doesn't really hurt me, but I still have the pressing urge to make it stop alltogether because its just not nice to have to deal with such kind of stuff repeatedly.

Comment: @Sursula: I would rather compare this to you being the neighbourhood watch that scares away the perpetrator such that nothing gets written on any window in the first place. That’s the inevitable ugly side of being a (community) moderator: You deal with crap, so everybody else doesn’t have to. Also, while at first glance this seems like a case where you can push some button to make the problem go away, it probably isn’t.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft [The IP should be blocked by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121366/217406) in 2012. But, why isn't it working on our site this time ? Or the user knows the system enough to use different IP addresses ?

Comment: @Nobody: I can only answer this to the extent that the system is working.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I got it. Your answer explains a lot.

Comment: @Sursula It's certainly okay for anyone to take a break from reviewing suggested edits for a moment, others will pick up the slack.